# Can pipe be private

Tags: angular

In angular2 if a component inside A module wants to reuse a component/directive declared inside another module B it must import that module. Since `pipes` go in the `declaration` just as components do, is the rule described above relevant for pipes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declarations: []` is "private" by default.

To become available for importing modules, you need to add it to `exports: [...]` in addition to `declarations: []`

Comment: thanks, yeah, so it's also relevant for the pipes, correct? And the other module has to import declarations, it's not enough to just add them to `exports` in the host module?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by "the other module has to import declarations". If you want to use components, directives, or pipes from a feature module, the feature module needs to declare and export them and where you want to use them, you need to import the feature **module**. You don't import declarations explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I meant module with declaration. Just wanted to make sure it applies to pipes as well.

Comment: Yup, all same for pipes.